# How to export opentsdb data to dolphindb

Tags: database, data-import, opentsdb, dolphindb

I want export some data from opentsdb,then import it into DolphinDB. 
In opentsdb, the metrics are device_id,ssid, the tags are battery_level,battery_status,battery_temperature,bssid,cpu_avg_1min,cpu_avg_5min,cpu_avg_15min,mem_free,mem_used and rssi.

In DolphinDB , I create a table as bellow,

```
COLS_READINGS   = `time`device_id`battery_level`battery_status`battery_temperature`bssid`cpu_avg_1min`cpu_avg_5min`cpu_avg_15min`mem_free`mem_used`rssi`ssid

TYPES_READINGS  = `DATETIME`SYMBOL`INT`SYMBOL`DOUBLE`SYMBOL`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`LONG`LONG`SHORT`SYMBOL

schema_readings = table(COLS_READINGS, TYPES_READINGS)
```

I find that the csv text file can import into DolphinDB, but I don't know how to export data to csv text file in Opentsdb. Is there a easy way to finish this work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using an HBase backend, the easiest way would be to access that directly. The [OpenTSDB schema](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/backends/hbase.html) describes in detail how to get the data you need.

The data is stored in one big table, but to save space, all metric names, tag keys and tag values are referenced using UIDs. These UIDs can be looked up in the UID table which stores that mapping in both directions.

You can write a small exporter in a language of your choice. The OpenTSDB code comes with an HBase client library, `asynchbase`, and has some tools to parse the raw data in its [Internal class](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/blob/master/src/core/Internal.java) which can make it a bit easier.